# Write a query to derive table B from table A

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to write a Query that derives table B from table A?

TABLE A

[image]

TABLE B

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple query such as:

```
SELECT ID , MAX(name), MAX(city) , MAX(state)
GROUP BY ID
```

Based on [MAX (Transact-SQL) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> For character columns, MAX finds the highest value in the collating sequence.